# Loop for array throws reading access exception

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, access-violation

I'm writing a simple battleship console game using clean C++. I'm trying to write a method, with will return a number of decks of the ship. It looks like this:

```
int Field::get_deck_number(int x, int y)
{
int temp_x = x,
    temp_y = y,
    deck_counter = 0;
if (arr[y][x] == field_sign || arr[y][x] == border_sign)
{
    return 0;
}
for (int direction = 0; direction < 4; direction++)
{
    temp_x = x;
    temp_y = y;
    while (arr[temp_y][temp_x] != field_sign || arr[temp_y][temp_x] != border_sign || arr[temp_y][temp_x] != tried_sign)
    {
        if (arr[temp_y][temp_x] == ship_sign || arr[temp_y][temp_x] == destroyed_sign)deck_counter++;
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            temp_y++;
            continue;
        }
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            temp_y--;
            continue;
        }
        if (direction == 2)
        {
            temp_x++;
            continue;
        }
        if (direction == 3)
        {
            temp_x--;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
return deck_counter;
}
```

The problem is with while loop condition. It is an infinite loop, so I will get read access violation after several iterations.

Comment: What is `this->arr`? Show a [mre] please.

Comment: `while(arr[x][y] != field_sign || arr[x][y] != border_sign || ...)` are you sure you want OR's there and not AND's??

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with improper use of logic OR and AND (||, &&). Also I find other logic problems in my code. Now it works properly.

```
int Field::get_deck_number(const int &x, const int &y)
{
int temp_x = x,
    temp_y = y,
    count = 0,
    deck_counter = 0;
if (arr[y][x] == field_sign || arr[y][x] == border_sign || arr[y][x] == tried_sign)
{
    return 0;
}
for (int direction = 0; direction < 4; direction++)
{
    temp_x = x;
    temp_y = y;
    count++;
    while (arr[temp_y][temp_x] != field_sign && arr[temp_y][temp_x] != border_sign && arr[temp_y][temp_x] != tried_sign)
    {   
        if (arr[temp_y][temp_x] == ship_sign || arr[temp_y][temp_x] == destroyed_sign)deck_counter++;
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            temp_y++;
            continue;
        }
        if (direction == 1)
        {
            temp_y--;
            continue;
        }
        if (direction == 2)
        {
            temp_x++;
            continue;
        }
        if (direction == 3)
        {
            temp_x--;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
return deck_counter - count + 1;
}
```